# Cannot install openssh-server on Debian9

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, openssh

I removed `openssh-server` due to I can't ssh connect to it suddenly(I can connect it normally yesterday). And I want to reinstall `openssh-server` by using `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`, but it couldn't be installed anymore, it shows `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`. There are the detailed logs.

```
$sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: adduser (>= 3.9) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpam-modules (>= 0.72-9) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpam-runtime (>= 0.76-14) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: procps but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ucf (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                           debconf-2.0
                  Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.01)
                  Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$sudo aptitude install openssh-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openssh-server openssh-sftp-server{a} 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  ncurses-term 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 323 kB of archives. After unpacking 923 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: openssh-server (< 1:8.1p1-5) but 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7 is to be installed
open: 1; closed: 0; defer: 0; conflict: 0                                      .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     openssh-server [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     openssh-server [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I search the internet and try many solutions, but none of them works

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/285605/how-to-fix-broken-packages
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409321/openssh-server-installation-results-in-error-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you

---

There are the information before I uninstall `openssh-server`.

Yestoday, I compiled ffmpeg with `--enable-ssl`, but it shows an error: `openssl not found`. I searched the internet and knowed that I should install the package `libssl-dev`. Then I use the command `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. It also shows an error like

```
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0l-1~deb9u3) but 1.1.1k-1 is to be installed 
Unable to Correct Problems You have Held Broken Packages
```

I searched the internet and get some answers. Then I use the command `sudo apt-get install libssl1.1=1.1.0l-1~deb9u3`. It works and fixes the error. At this moment, there are two different versions of the same library `libssl` co-exist on my system. One is `libssl1.0.2` and another is `libssl1.1`.

Today, I found that I can't ssh connect to my system. I want to uninstall `openssh-server` and reinstall it. But I got errors that showed above. Is it because there are two different versions of the same library in my system? When I try to remove `libssl1.0.2`, but i found many libraries depends on it. When I try to remove `libssl1.1`, it shows the error `depends: dh-autoreconf (>= 12) but it is not going to be installed. Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages`

---

There is the information of my system.

```
$uname -a
Linux linaro-alip 4.4.189 #24 SMP Tue Jul 21 17:01:59 CST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.189 (rpdzkj@rpdzkj) (gcc version 6.3.1 20170404 (Linaro GCC 6.3-2017.05) ) #24 SMP Tue Jul 21 17:01:59 CST 2020
```

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

```
$apt policy 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 100 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch-backports/contrib arm64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stretch-backports,n=stretch-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=contrib,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 100 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch-backports/non-free arm64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stretch-backports,n=stretch-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=non-free,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 100 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stretch-backports,n=stretch-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch/contrib arm64 Packages
     release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch/non-free arm64 Packages
     release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
     release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=arm64
     origin mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
Pinned packages:
```

```
$ apt policy openssh-{server,client}
openssh-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7
  Version table:
     1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7 500
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
     1:7.4p1-10+deb9u6 500
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
openssh-client:
  Installed: 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7
  Candidate: 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7 500
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.4p1-10+deb9u6 500
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
```

Comment: What does `apt policy` show? It seems you’re pulling in packages from multiple releases.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have updated the results of `apt policy`. I am using the mirror site that debian recommended.

Comment: Thanks, that looks fine. It doesn’t explain why `libssl1.1` version 1.1.1k-1 was a candidate previously (that’s the Debian 11 version). What does `apt policy openssh-{server,client}` show?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have updated the results of `apt policy openssh-{server,client}`. Thank you!

Comment: @StephenKitt Hi